# How to keep a winform responsive while a heavy painting is underway

Tags: winforms

My program draws heavily on a winform. During the drawing, the winform is not responding. How to make it responding to my mouse? I want to use another thread to draw to the winform, but I am afraid I am going to meet the infamous cross-threads-access-conrtrol error.

Comment: In what way is it drawing? Is it painting with GDI+ or is it rearranging/creating (user)controls?

Comment: I'm using the System.Drawing.Graphics, so it should be GDI+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a great MSDN article that might help you: [Give Your .NET-based Application a Fast and Responsive UI with Multiple Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300429.aspx)

When I was facing similar problems, it helped me a great deal to understand what to do.

Also, you might want to have a look at [Parallel Programming in .NET Framework 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/01/parallel-programming-in-net-framework-4-getting-started.aspx). This series also includes a strategy with calculations that are spread over multiple synchronized threads, all with using out-of-the-box .NET collections. This is not as complicatesd as it may sound. Just give it a try. :-)

Also, if you have the chance to use the upcoming .NET enhancements, it would be worth to try [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is GDI+ painting you can do all of your drawing on a separate bitmap in a separate thread (instead of drawing directly to screen) - and when you're done: copy the whole bitmap onto the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BackgroundWorker` class to keep your winform responsive. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you are performing UI stuff. You have to come back into the UI thread to do so. All I could recommend, is drawing a bit, letting the UI thread process any events, draw again a bit.

Thats probably the best way round, but it isnt easy to do ... Far less easier than just running non UI jobs in another thread ...